# How do I take only the numbers from a string and append into a list in python?

Tags: python

I want to take only the years in this string and place in a list

```
a = "Sam works in a company abc in New York. He joined the company last year 2019. Before joining ABC, he used to work for a small firm in Arizona. He worked there from 2015 to 2018. Before moving to Arizona Sam used to live in South Dakota and he has been living there since 2000's"

b = a.split()
year = []
for i in b:
    if i.isdigit():
        year.append(i)
print(b)
```

Comment: I can see several issues with the code. What particular problem are you noting?

Comment: Im trying to take only the years in the string (like 2009 and 2015) and place them in a list

Comment: How do you propose going about determining which numbers represent years and which might represent quantities or other arbitrary measures?

Comment: Your first problem is that `a` is set to only the first line of the text, so you're only iterating over the first line. But I see you've edited that.
Next, you're printing `b` not `year`.
Finally, you're missing `2019.` because split doesn't remove the period and `2019.` is not `isdigit()`

Answer (score 3):

The most straightforward approach to solving this is using `re.findall` to find all 4 digit numbers surrounded by word boundaries.

```
>>> a = "Sam works in a company abc in New York. He joined the company last year 2019. Before joining ABC, he used to work for a small firm in Arizona. He worked there from 2015 to 2018. Before moving to Arizona Sam used to live in South Dakota and he has been living there since 2000's"
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'\b ( \d{4} ) \b', a, re.X)
['2019', '2015', '2018', '2000']
```